# Can a application built with server certificate inserted in it?

Tags: sockets, security, ssl, tcp, openssl

I have a client a application which is distributed to multiple clients. Sometimes this application acts as server for some processes.I want the communication to be over ssl.  I want to insert the server certificate inside the application and publish to multiple clients. Is this design a good idea?

Is there any real time product example which is using this design?

Comment: You need to consider the case when the certificate gets expired or compromised, in that case to change the certificate you will have to redeploy you application at all clients

Comment: @Pras It will be handled by patch updates to all clients

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly add TLS communication this way, but as I understand your question, all application instances would receive the same certificate and they could thus impersonate each other. If someone extracts the private key for the certificate in one app they can decrypt all the communication for all processes and applications. Just the fact that the key is distributed to multiple environments outside your control could justify revocation of the certificate an any time.

The design is not a good idea if you want proper TLS communication with a publicly trusted root. The processes and applications will likely have to communicate using untrusted certificates, possibly self signed certificates.